# 停止 vs. 停住 usage/difference?

Tags: meaning, usage

I am quite confused with the usage of both words as the some of the meaning is overlapping based in English translations. The dictionary shows that 停止 = stop, cease, halt while for 停住 = stop, halt. So what situation do you guys use 停止 and 停住?

Answer (score 1):

Both 停 and 止 contains the meaning of 'to stop'.

- "停止" is a compound word verb for 'to stop'
- "停住" = "to stop (successfully/ and keep it this way). It is made up of the verb '停' and it's [result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complement) '住' (住 as a result complement denotes: 1. successfully; 2. in a continuous state)

> 停止 is usually used as an intransitive verb or auxiliary verb

Example :

(intransitive verb): 操作停止 (operation stops); 任务停止 (mission stops)

(auxiliary verb): 停止攻擊 (stop attacking); 停止操作 (stop operating)

> "停住" can be use transitive or intransitive

Example :

(transitive verb): 他停住車子 (he stops the car)

(intransitive verb) 車子停住了 (the car stops)

Answer (score 1):

停住 is often used for **tangible objects**, 停止 for **intangible ones**. For example, 停止进攻（进攻 is intangible）， 把车停住（车 is tangible）;

There could be some exceptions, but that rule could work most of time.

Answer (score 0):

停住 is often used as a command in language similar to:

> stop!

or

> halt!

Like you might hear from a policeman or a person of authority.

---

[住](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Advanced_result_complements#.E4.BD.8F_as_Result_Complement) as a grammar point has two functions:

> 住 can be used after a verb to express a "coming to a halt." These verbs are limited.

for instance:

> 抓住那个小偷！
>   Catch that thief!

and

> 住 can also be used to express "undertaking an action firmly" or "tightly."

like:

> 你必须抓住机会。
>   You must seize the opportunity tightly.

So, the emphasis of 住 in 停住 is again: halt.

---

停止 is used as a verb more akin to:

> to stop

or

> to cease

Here's an example from [91dub](https://www.91dub.com/search/%E5%81%9C%E6%AD%A2?type=search):

> The murders stopped. The disappearances stopped.
>   杀人事件停止了 失踪事件也停止了